# Custom sorting products when title is made of letters and numbers in WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

So, I did some digging but wasn't able to find the correct way to do this.

I have some products on WooCommerce (Wordpress), but their title is composed of Letters mixed with numbers.
I need those products to be print like this (e.g.):

FNC21000-C
FNC24500-C
FNC232500-C

But, of course, Wordpress gives me:

FNC21000-C
FNC232500-C
FNC24500-C

Is there anyway to achieve this?

I think there's something I might do on WP_Query but I'm really a newbie with PHP, and I know some of the possible fixes are on PHP, some others on MySQL... and the fact that the title is BOTH string and integer, makes me feel clueless on how to write this...

Does anyone has some suggestions?

Below, class-wc-query.php, which I BELIEVE to be the file I need to edit:

```
/**
 * Returns an array of arguments for ordering products based on the selected values.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return array
 */
public function get_catalog_ordering_args( $orderby = '', $order = '' ) {
    // Get ordering from query string unless defined
    if ( ! $orderby ) {
        $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

        // Get order + orderby args from string
        $orderby_value = explode( '-', $orderby_value );
        $orderby       = esc_attr( $orderby_value[0] );
        $order         = ! empty( $orderby_value[1] ) ? $orderby_value[1] : $order;
    }

    $orderby = strtolower( $orderby );
    $order   = strtoupper( $order );
    $args    = array();

    // default - menu_order
    $args['orderby'] = "strlen('title') => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC'";
    //      $args['orderby']  = 'title';
    $args['order']    = $order == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    $args['meta_key'] = '';

    switch ( $orderby ) {
        case 'rand' :
            $args['orderby']  = 'rand';
        break;
        case 'date' :
            $args['orderby']  = 'date ID';
            $args['order']    = $order == 'ASC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
        break;
        case 'price' :
            $args['orderby']  = "meta_value_num ID";
            $args['order']    = $order == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
        break;
        case 'popularity' :
            $args['meta_key'] = 'total_sales';

            // Sorting handled later though a hook
            add_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( $this, 'order_by_popularity_post_clauses' ) );
        break;
        case 'rating' :
            // Sorting handled later though a hook
            add_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( $this, 'order_by_rating_post_clauses' ) );
        break;
        case 'title' :
        $args['orderby'] = "strlen('title') => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC'";
//$args['orderby']  = 'meta_value meta_value_num title';
            $args['order']    = $order == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        break;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', $args );
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure a simple code telling WC to first sort based on the length of the titles found, and then sort it based on the title, would be enough to me... I'm just not able to write the code down :(

this is what I achieved so far but it's not working:

    `case 'title' :
        $args['orderby'] = "mb_strlen('title') => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC'"; 
        $args['order'] = $order == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    break;`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, simply call [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be2880fea5027a615479f030fac0962039654e4c))

```
$array=['FND100000-C','FNC24500-C','FNC232500-C','FMC30000-C','FNC21000-C'];
natsort($array);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  3 => 'FMC30000-C',
  4 => 'FNC21000-C',
  1 => 'FNC24500-C',
  2 => 'FNC232500-C',
  0 => 'FND100000-C',
)
```

In MYSQL, as long as the format is...

- 3 letters then
- a series of numbers then
- a hyphen then
- one or more characters

...you can order by calling [SUBSTRING()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php) and [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)

Table & Query: ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d47b6/1))

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `PrdID` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`PrdID`) VALUES
('FMC30000-C'),
('FNC21000-B'),
('FNC21000-C'),
('FNC232500-C'),
('FNC24500-C'),
('FND100000-C');

ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PrdID`);

SELECT PrdID,
       SUBSTRING(PrdID,1,3),
       SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrdID,'-',1),4),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrdID,'-',-1)
FROM `test`
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING(PrdID,1,3),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrdID,'-',1),4) AS UNSIGNED),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrdID,'-',-1)
```

Output:

```
PrdID       | SUBSTRING(PrdID,1,3) | SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrdID,'-',1),4) | SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrdID,'-',-1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FMC30000-C  |         FMC          |                  30000                    |               C
FNC21000-B  |         FNC          |                  21000                    |               B
FNC21000-C  |         FNC          |                  21000                    |               C
FNC24500-C  |         FNC          |                  24500                    |               C
FNC232500-C |         FNC          |                  232500                   |               C
FND100000-C |         FND          |                  100000                   |               C
```

---

Here's a shot in the dark from a non-WordPress developer...

<s>$args['orderby'] = "substr('title',0,3) => 'ASC', substr(strstr('title','-',true),3) => 'ASC', substr('title',strpos('title','-')+1) => 'ASC'";</s>

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a6302d2b7d77d37e4479cad4fddb7014e8be96c)

After looking at: 
 https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-query.php it looks like the orderby components are just space delimited, not comma delimited.  Try this:

```
$args['orderby'] = "substr('title',0,3) substr(strstr('title','-',true),3) substr('title',strpos('title','-')+1)";
$args['order'] = $order==='DESC'?'DESC':'ASC';
```

Comment: Ok, TKS for replying. But WordPress will build its array dynamically from db (MySql), so I'm not sure how to correctly apply this... And, again, I'm not really sure in which file I should apply the code (although I'm pretty sure it's wc-query)

Comment: @MateusOliveira I've added a mysql method that should be reliable.  Can this work for you?  (Of course, the SELECT clause is irrelevant / purely for demonstration -- you only need the ORDER BY clause.)

Comment: I'm really sorry to be that stupid, but I'm newbie enough to not be able to apply this on my code...

Comment: Well, I'm not a Wordpress developer.  I can lead you to water, but I can't make you drink.  Good luck.

Comment: Wordpress builds its array directly from db, which already has all the products registered. Unfortunatelly, I don't have access to the db... So I won't be able to execute anything on MySQL... I know I'm able to request the db values, organize them in the array and then sort using natsort, but I'm not sure about how to acchieve this. I'll paste WooCommerce class-wc-query.php code on the question (I BELIEVE this is the one I have to work on)

Comment: Judging by this `$args['orderby'] = "strlen('title') => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC'";` I should be able to convert my mysql function calls to php calls and barf up a string to suit.

Comment: @MateusOliveira I've added my "best guess" at a WP method.  I am rather curious to know if that will actually work.  I will be offline for while (midnight now, I'll check back in the morning).

Comment: It didn't work, so far... But I had to let this project on Standby, for now. May I contact you when we get back to this, or at least mention you here? Thanks a lot man for trying to help :)

Comment: hey, do you think a simple sort based first on the length of the title, then the title itself, would be enough? I'm really sorry, but do you think you can help me writing that?
this is what I achieved so far but it's not working:

`case 'title' :
      $args['orderby'] = "mb_strlen('title') => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC'";
      $args['order']    = $order == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
break;`

Comment: @MateusOliveira I posted another WP shot-in-the-dark.  Let me know how that one goes.

Comment: And about your previous question: would a preliminary sort using `strlen()` work?  Yes, IF the only component of the string that has variable length is the numeric portion.  However, if the leading or trailing alphabetical components can differ in length, then that approach will fail.

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work... I'm really not sure why.

As from what it concerns the strlen(), yeah, the only component variable is the numeric portion. The alphabetical prefix has fixed length... I think I should use mb_strlen() though, right?

Comment: I don't think you'll be expecting any accented letters, so `mb_strlen()` is overkill and slower.  `strlen()` will serve you just fine.

Comment: At this point, I think it is a fair suggestion for you to research how to add a function or hook or whatever and allow some raw mysql code to do this job accurately for you.

Comment: I've found out that it's something close to this:

`$args['orderby'] = array(strlen('title') => 'ASC','title' => 'ASC');`

but wasn't able to proceed much more...